# Bootstrap: Vertical Align across all devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Update:

I seem to have everything working except when testing on an actual iPhone. On my iPhone 6 the layout does not appear like it does when testing on the chrome emulator - any ideas? Its very odd indeed, one of my white CSS arrows does not display either. I have attached some screenshots of both the emulator and the phone.
[image: Screenshot from iPhone][image: Emulator screenshot]

---

I have created a Bootstrap grid using the following:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"><img src="images/articles/services/curtain-sliders.png" alt="curtain sliders" /></div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-cont left-arrow"><h3 class="grid-text">Curtain Sliders</h3></div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"><img src="images/articles/services/abnormal-loads.png" alt="abnormal loads" /></div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-cont left-arrow"><h3 class="grid-text">Abnormal Loads</h3></div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-3 col-sm-6"><img src="images/articles/services/hazardous-goods.png" alt="hazardous goods" /></div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-3 col-sm-6 text-cont right-arrow"><h3 class="grid-text">Hazardous Goods</h3></div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-3 col-sm-6"><img src="images/articles/services/step-frame-plant-movers.png" alt="step frame plant movers" /></div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-3 col-sm-6 text-cont right-arrow"><h3 class="grid-text">Heavy Plant Movement</h3></div>
</div>
</div>
```

The divs with class 'text-cont' needs to have the H3 text vertically aligned in the middle, so to address this I have used the following css:

```
.text-cont {
    height:210px;
    line-height: 215px;
}
.grid-text {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

This works fine on my Macbook but obviously is not responsive thus the grid becomes misaligned on different screen sizes. I'm a bootstrap novice, thus I've been hunting around looking for an efficient way to do this to ensure the divs are responsive.

The page in question can be found [here](http://mccaul.cloudaccess.host/), the grid is at the bottom. If anyone could suggest any definitive resources or a simple solution, I would be most appreciative.
Regards
D

Answer (score 0):

Try using flexbox.

```
.text-cont{
       display: -webkit-flex;
       display: -moz-box;
       display: -ms-flexbox;
       display:flex;
       align-items:center;
       justify-content:center;
    }
```

If you wanted to give a height to your `.text-cont` class, you can give a height. If you dont want to give a height, then add a flexbox to the parent container too.

```
.zen-module-body .row{
           display: -webkit-flex;
           display: -moz-box;
           display: -ms-flexbox;
           display:flex;
}
```

In the responsive view you can add, to deal with responsive view

```
@media (max-width: 767px){

    .zen-module-body .row{
        flex-wrap:wrap;
    }

    .zen-module-body .container-fluid .row:first-child .col-sm-push-3.left-arrow:after{
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        right: auto;
        left: 100%;
    }

    .zen-module-body .container-fluid .row:last-child .col-sm-pull-3.right-arrow:after{
        transform: none;
        right: 100%;
        left: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Veena - This seems to work in all but one thing - I use push/pull to position the elements and this seems to stop working on an iPad and the boxes become out of order. Any suggestions? I'm going to keep fiddling about and see if I can figure it out :)

Comment: @Dtorr1981. Thanks for your response. You can use `flex-wrap:wrap;` or `flex-direction:column;` etc (depends on your design) to manage your position of elements  in ipad or mobile responsive designs.

Comment: Hi Veena, I seem to have got everything working - Except on my iPhone 6 the layout does not appear like it does when testing on the chrome emulator - any ideas? Its very odd indeed, one of my white CSS arrows does not display either.

Comment: Hi Dtorr1981, please refer to the edited responsive codes given in the answer. I hope it may solve your issue. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS to this:

```
.text-cont {
    height: 253px;
    line-height: 253px;
}
```

This should keep the grid aligned on smaller devices. The reason it becomes misaligned is because your images a much taller than the `.text-cont` div on smaller devices.

Answer (score 0):

Update your css with this

```
.text-cont {
    height:314px;
}
.grid-text {
    position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```